# MySQL - efficient regexp (or like) query

Tags: mysql, regex

I have two tables, a `performer` table and a `redirect` table. The `performer` table has a column called `slug`. The `redirect` table has a column called `source`.

Both the `source` and `slug` columns have unique key indexes.

An example of a `slug` column data is something like:

```
this-is-a-slug
```

An example of a `source` column data is something like:

```
this-is-a-slug.s12345
```

I want an efficient query that gives me all the rows in `redirect` that have a `source` column that starts with a `slug` and the ".s" characters, followed by a number digits.

I tried this:

```
select source from redirect
join performer on
source regexp concat('^', slug, '.s[0-9]+$');
```

It was extremely slow. So I decided to be less restrictive and tried this:

```
select source from redirect
join performer on
source like concat(slug, ".s%");
```

It was still slow.

Is there a way I can do this efficiently?

Comment: No, this is never going to be efficient until you change your schema (see Rick's answer below). And 10s of thousands of rows is a *small* table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abandon the current plans.

Add a column to `redirect` that has the `slug`.  This is a one-time change to the table, plus changing your code to insert it.

If you are running 5.7 or MariaDB, use a virtual column, possibly with a materialized index.

BTW, here's another way to split the string:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('this-is-a-slug.s12345', '.', 1);
+--------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('this-is-a-slug.s12345', '.', 1) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| this-is-a-slug                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

If the 's' is critical, then study these:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('this-is-a-slug.s12345', '.s', 1);
+---------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('this-is-a-slug.s12345', '.s', 1) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| this-is-a-slug                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('this-is-a-slug.invalid', '.s', 1);
+----------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('this-is-a-slug.invalid', '.s', 1) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| this-is-a-slug.invalid                             |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. "Add a column to source that has the slug". I'm not sure I understand that. "source" is a column. Did you mean to "redirect"? If that's the case, then it would be a simple join on the slug column right? Why then would I need to use the SUBSTRING_INDEX function?

Comment: Fixed `redirect`.  `SUBSTRING_INDEX` was yet another way of dealing with extracting the 'slug'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
join performer on left(source,length(slug)+2)=concat(slug, ".s")
```

But it seems to me it is the same